# Open a Tab Panel when user clicks on a button

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a `Window`, and when i click on a button i will pop open it (as a `pop up`). Here's my code and it works fine.

```
var w= Ext.widget('mywindow');
w.show();
```

Now, i have a `tab bar panel`, where when the user clicks the button i need to open it (**But, not as a Pop-up**). It should occupy the whole screen (**Replace the previous view**). How should i do this ?

The definition of my tab panel

```
Ext.define('App.view.TabPanelClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.persontabpanel',
    .....
```

**UPDATE**

```
launch: function() {   

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'card',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel', 
                items: { xtype: 'firstPanel' }

            },....
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use card layout to replace one view with another. Alternatively you can create a window with maximized:true config.

Comment: What does `maximized:true` do ? Will it size the content of the window to fit the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to go about this is to put the tabpanel inside of a viewport and give it a `layout: 'card'` config to cover any other views, a `layout: 'fit'` config would work better if this is the only view you have in the viewport. Windows aren't children of the ExtJS viewport so a window and a tabpanel would only be one item in the viewport.

A viewport will keep it's contents sized to match the browser window size even when it gets resized. See the docs on viewport [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport).

Comment: I have created my viewport inside the `launch: function()`. How can i make all the content to fit the browser ?

Comment: @sharonHwk give the top component of your content a `layout: 'fit'` config and include that top component inside of the `viewport`'s `items` array.